# iOS efficient executable decryption

Tags: ios, encryption, arm, copy-protection

I wanna preface by saying that I am just a newbie, which is trying to understand the complex jailbreak universe. I am no software cracker or reverse engineer, just a curious guy.

So, recently I have started using Hopper disassembler, and began studying ARM Assembly. However, I came up with [i0n1c's dumpdecrypted](https://github.com/stefanesser/dumpdecrypted), a C script which basically dumps the unencrypted executable for any iOS application. I also have read about Mach-O files structure, and how Apple protects their code against hackers.

Finally, I tried disassembling some games on my device, just for having some Assembly to read and try to apply my basic knowledge. I noticed that some executables decompile without any problem, and I have all (or most of them) of the Objective-C methods and declarations in Hopper's left pane. Also Hopper automatically recognizes the executable loader as `ARMv7`.

Now, with other executables, most of the code is still encrypted. And Hopper sets the loader as `ARMv7s`.

So I researched, and tried even some cracking tweaks, such as `clutch`. I noticed that `clutch` effectively dumps and packs IPAs files for the games which code was all decrypted by i0n1c's script. It instead fails on the executables that `dumpdecrypted` leaves semi-decrypted, with this error message:

```
Cracking XXX...
error: Cannot crack ARMV6 portion of fat binary.
error: Could not crack binary
Failed.
```

So, some executables use 2 different ARM architectures? How's that possible? That's why Hopper sets the loader as `ARMv7s`?

My real question is: Is there an efficient way to decrypt all (or like the 90%) of the code of an iOS executable? And why some are dumped without problems why others are not?

Again, I am not a software cracker, I am learning ARM for my personal knowledge and for testing my apps.

I was curious about this strange encryption. If anyone can answer my question, thanks in advance!

*I also don't know if StackOverflow is the right place to post this, but I assume yes, since assembly is still a programming language.*

Comment: Many iOS executables are compiled for multiple architectures. The most common nowadays are armv7, armv7s, and arm64.

Comment: I thought that. But then I checked `dumpdecrypted`'s makefile: 

`GCC_UNIVERSAL=$(GCC_BASE) -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -arch arm64`

There are set other architectures, so why it doesn't decompile them?

Comment: I'm really not familiar with most of what you're discussing, I was just answering a question you had (but not answering the main question, so it's just a comment).

Comment: I understand. Thanks anyway for the reply!